# Why key length needs to be specified when db_index=False?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a `TextField` declared as `foo = models.TextField(unique=True, db_index=False)`, but on migration i still get an error saying

```
BLOB/TEXT column 'foo' used in key specification without a key length
```

I thought the length only needs to be specified if an index is created. Doesn't `db_index=False` prevent an index from creating? I'm using MySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because **unique** keyword will automatically generate an index for the field, even if you specify `db_index=False`.

You should think of it like, `unique=True` will overwrite `db_index=False` in this case.

#### Updated:

If you look at the SQL statement (use [sqlmigrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate) if you're >= Django 1.7), you can see it clearly that `unique=True` overwrites `db_index=False`:

```
... "foo" text NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

So, if you do not want to have the index at all, you need to drop `unique=True` altogether.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right. So I guess all I can do is to drop the `unique` attribute and lose the uniqueness constraint?

Comment: If your intention is not to create an index at all, then YES.